# how to write a nginx rewrite to route all urls with a specific query var

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have several (15+) of these urls

site.com/q=something/plus-this-subfolder

site.com/q=somethingelse/plus-someother-subfolder

I want to rewrite all these to the root /.  These are very old content and do not need to route anywhere else.

I have tried:

```
if ($request_uri ~ "([^\?]*)\?(.*)q=([^&]*)&?(.*)") {
    set $original_path $1;
    rewrite ^ "${original_path}" permanent;
}
```

AND

```
if ($arg_q) {
    return 301 /;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what issues you're having, especially with the second approach you mention, which should definitely work.

Comment: I have no idea why but I tried the second answer again and it worked. thanks for pushing me to try again

Comment: glad it worked!  i posted it as an answer, then. :-)

Comment: since the problem is resolved, could you accept the answer?  thanks!

Comment: ping -- is there any issue with the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, your second approach should work just fine.

```
if ($arg_q) {
    return 301 /;
}
```

Comment: My apologies if you were not rewarded the bounty.  Is there any other way to gift you the bounty?

Comment: Only way would be to start a new one (on either this one or any other question).

Comment: @TJSherrill, oh, wow, thank you!  i didn't expect you'll actually start another one.  just make sure to award it this time -- since you've accepted my answer before you've restarted it, it won't be awarded the bounty automatically, but i think you should still be able to manually award it to an existing answer.  let me know if you have any questions!